# Spring Batch Job not launching

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

`I have just started with spring batch . I have done all of my configurations for spring batch . But the jobs are not getting launched . Instead tomcat server is getting up.Here is my configuration

```
 @Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<CustomerDetailsDTO> customerCsvFileReader(){
   return  new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<CustomerDetailsDTO>()
             .name("customerCsvFileReader")
             .delimited()
             .names(JobUtils.CREATE_CUSTOMER_DTO_FIELDS)
             .linesToSkip(1)      //skip the header
             .fieldSetMapper(new CustomerDetailsDTOMapper())
             .targetType(CustomerDetailsDTO.class)
             .resource(new ClassPathResource("cust_data.csv"))
             .build();

 }



    @Bean
    public Job sampleJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step sampleStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("sampleJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(sampleStep)
                .build();
    }


@Bean
public Step sampleStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,ItemWriter<CustomerDetailsDTO> restItemWriter) {
    return new StepBuilder("sampleStep", jobRepository)
            .<CustomerDetailsDTO, CustomerDetailsDTO>chunk(1, transactionManager)
            .reader(customerCsvFileReader())
            .writer(restItemWriter)
            .build();
}`
```

But the job is not at all launching. I am using `RestTemplate`  in my writer . So I included `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.Where am I going wrong?

Below are the logs

```
2023-02-28T00:55:45.866+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.annotation.BatchRegistrar      : Finished Spring Batch infrastructure beans configuration in 16 ms.
2023-02-28T00:55:47.689+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-28T00:55:47.721+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-28T00:55:47.722+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-02-28T00:55:48.381+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-28T00:55:48.384+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3483 ms
2023-02-28T00:55:48.701+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-02-28T00:55:49.079+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:4bd9ced2-4ff8-4416-9e0d-0ec290622c63 user=SA
2023-02-28T00:55:49.082+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-02-28T00:55:49.096+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: H2
2023-02-28T00:55:49.206+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-02-28T00:55:49.217+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] .c.a.BatchObservabilityBeanPostProcessor : No Micrometer observation registry found, defaulting to ObservationRegistry.NOOP
2023-02-28T00:55:49.220+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2023-02-28T00:55:49.773+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-28T00:55:49.784+05:30  INFO 924 --- [           main] r2sSpringBatchStarterTemplateApplication : Started Br2sSpringBatchStarterTemplateApplication in 5.743 seconds (process running for 6.844)
```

I am very new to this spring batch .I expected the job to run

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SpringBoot 3 you need to disable `@EnableBatchProcessing` . This is already mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287102/spring-batch-5-0-with-spring-boot-tasklet-job-not-starting-automatically) question

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your class is not annotated with `@EnableBatchProcessing` - it is no longer required in Spring Boot 3. And adding it will cause the batch job NOT to run. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#enablebatchprocessing-is-now-discouraged

Answer (score 0):

1. Your class with batch-related beans should be annotated with `@Configuration` annotation
2. Consider `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation in your configuration.
3. Also check whether you have in your application properties (actually it is enabled by default, but anyway):

---

```
spring:
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: true
```

Comment: I have the above annotations already configured. spring.batch.job.enabled property is not there in my properties file