# Spring Batch 5 changes breaks my JobRepository configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I had to upgrade my app to Spring Batch 5 as multiple classes were deprecated as a requirement to moving to Spring 3. However my JobRepository is now failing to start because of a null "this.incrementerFactory" is null. I tried using a default incrementerFactory but that throws an exception. Here is my configuration

Here is the application.yml

```
spring:
  batch:
    job:
      enabled: true #  set this to true if you want the batch job to start as soon as Spring loads
      name: productFetchJob
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always
      schema: schema-h2.sql
 
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

This portion is no longer supported and worked

```
           jdbc:
               datasource:
               schema: schema-h2.sql
               auto-commit: true
```

```java
    public class JobRepositoryConfig {

    @Qualifier("jobMetaDataSource")
    final DataSource jobMetaDataSource;

    @Value("${processing.thread-pool-size}") int threadPoolSize;


    @Bean("jobRepositoryTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager jobRepositoryTransactionManager(@Qualifier("jobMetaDataSource") DataSource jobMetaDataSource){
        return  new DataSourceTransactionManager(jobMetaDataSource);
    }


    @Bean
    public JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory(@Qualifier("jobRepositoryTransactionManager")PlatformTransactionManager jobRepositoryTransactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(jobMetaDataSource);
        var incrementerFactory = new DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory(jobMetaDataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(jobRepositoryTransactionManager);
        factory.setIncrementerFactory(incrementerFactory);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean("productJobRepository")
    public JobRepository productJobRepository(@Qualifier("jobRepositoryTransactionManager")PlatformTransactionManager jobRepositoryTransactionManager) throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(jobMetaDataSource);
        var incrementerFactory = new DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory(jobMetaDataSource);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(jobRepositoryTransactionManager);
        jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIncrementerFactory(incrementerFactory);
        return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean("productAppJobLauncher")
    public JobLauncher productAppJobLauncher(@Qualifier("productJobRepository") JobRepository productJobRepository) {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(jobLauncherTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(productJobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean("jobLauncherTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor jobLauncherTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(threadPoolSize);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(threadPoolSize);
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Here is the exception

Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'productJobRepository' threw exception with message: Cannot invoke "String.toUpperCase()" because "incrementerType" is null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBe

I don't understand what I need to provide now other than this, can someone help?

Why would a design not make use of sensible defaults. If you can specify a database type the connection etc. why should a configuration break which used to work because of the setIncrementerFactory. When I created one, the next failure was,.that there was no conversion service, what? I simply gave up because it was quickly evident when looking at the implementation of the JobRepository, that a lot of upfront configuration was being done and that unless I added all those, it was going to be a losing battle.  Like I said, I gave up and removed all the custom configuration and simply injected a JobRepository, how frustrating. JobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory etc. why? These have been present all this while, I solved the problem otherwise.

The datasource property of jdbc has been removed. The schema can only be specified directly, but now it complains that it cannot find  schema-h2.sql. Also, the auto-commit property has been removed, just frustrating all these features which have existed for years get changed and the replacement configurations just don't work. i dislike this about Spring and will use Quarkus or other more stable dependency injection frameworks in the future. Changing classes is one thing but when the new configurations don't work out of the box, that's a whole new different ball game.

This exception is thrown because spring cannot find the schema for the JobRepository database when it used to find it before under jdbc.datasource.schema in the spring.data attribute.

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-11-25T15:45:49.270-06:00 ERROR 27938 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'runController' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/controller/RunController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productJobScheduler' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/scheduler/ProductJobScheduler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3: Error creating bean with name 'ProductJobConfig' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/job/ProductJobConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'updateProductsStep' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/step/data/UpdateProductsStep.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceProductizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceProductizerConfiguration.class]: No schema scripts found at product 'schema-h2.sql'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryproductization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
at com.inventory.product.batch.productBatchApplication.main(ProductBatchApplication.java:25)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productJobScheduler' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/scheduler/ProductJobScheduler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3: Error creating bean with name 'productJobConfig' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/job/ProductJobConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'updateProductsStep' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/step/data/UpdateProductsStep.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceproductizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceproductizerConfiguration.class]: No schema scripts found at product 'schema-h2.sql'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productJobConfig' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/job/ProductJobConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'updateProductsStep' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/step/data/UpdateProductsStep.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceproductizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceproductizerConfiguration.class]: No schema scripts found at product 'schema-h2.sql'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'updateProductsStep' defined in file [/Users/projects/catalog-product-batch/build/classes/java/main/com/inventory/product/batch/step/data/UpdateProductsStep.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceProductizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceProductizerConfiguration.class]: No schema scripts found at product 'schema-h2.sql'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceProductizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceProductizerConfiguration.class]: No schema scripts found at product 'schema-h2.sql'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.productizeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No schema scripts found at product 'schema-h2.sql'
at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.getScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.java:129)
at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.java:106)
at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.applySchemaScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.java:98)
at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.productizeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.java:76)
at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseproductizer.java:66)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.productizeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
... 92 common frames omitted

> Task :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace, it is currently truncated. If you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, I can take a look.

Comment: It's just the crazy design decisions that Spring Batch 5 introduces with all its deprecations.  I solved it by simply removing my configuration, making the job repository database configuration the primary one and injecting the JobRepository.

Comment: Take the Hibernate library, by simply providing a database dialect, the EntityManager simply works. My argument ins this, providing a datasource and database type should be enough for Spring to provide reasonable defaults without old code breaking. Defaults should apply unless I override them myself. Unfortunately, after including an IncrementerFactory, the next error was that I had not provided a Conversion service, and I just realized what I was in for when I looked at the code for JobRepository, absolutely ridiculous in my opinion

Comment: By default, the job repository will be configured based on the provided datasource. The configuration you shared is not necessary, that is what Spring Batch will configure by default, which you confirmed `I solved it by simply removing my configuration`. Spring Batch 5 tremendously simplifies the configuration compared to Spring Batch 4 (having to override `BatchConfigurer`, manual configuration of the transaction manager, etc). If you share an example with v4, I would be happy to help you migrate it to v5.

Comment: The other portion of the stacktrace is related to the Step configurations failing as a result of not being able to instantiate the JobRepository. The only portion I need to fix the issue at the first attempt was to provide a IncrementerFactory as indicated in the stacktrace. The JobRepository could not be instantiated because of that. Once I fixed that issue Spring started complaining about the ConversionService. I have provided the datasource code which my custom implementation depends on. That's all the code needed to create the custom JobRepository configuration.

Comment: Regarding `schema-h2.sql`, this is not related to Spring Batch 5 but rather to the way Spring Boot 3 initializes the schema, which should work OOTB as shared here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75288283/5019386. Are those properties defined in the right place in the yml file? WRT to the conversion service, you need to override the default one only if you have custom type of job parameters, but this should also work OOTB for common types. Reading the update of your question, you seem to have fixed the issue related to `incrementerFactory`, correct? Again, happy to help if you share a repository.

Comment: Yes I had fixed that, but the next error was ConversionService missing. From that error I realized that for the custom configuration, Spring Batch was not providing defaults but expecting the full configuration for every dependency, which caused me to give up.

Comment: No, it doesn't work OOTB, otherwise I would not be getting an exception. What I see from the example you referenced is that a schema is not specifically defined. It now seems it is impossible to easily create a minimal custom JobRepository implementation. That used to be possible to do with the configuration I provided which used to work in version 4. Whilst it makes sense to change classes, a future implementation should not break configurations which utlilize the core framework, that's what's most frustrating about this upgrade. I  had to remove my custom JobRepository

Comment: I'm really annoyed by this Spring Batch 5. It breaks core engineering principles, no backward compatibility with the core classes that haven't changed, specifically JobRepository. As long as a developer is not interfering with the internal implementations, the core exposed functions should still work the same without breaking, this is not the case here. The behavour is just unpredicatable. Take a look at my JobRepository configuration and give me a reason why that should not work. Justify why it shouldn't.

Comment: Spring library changes are sometimes just cavalier with little thought to it's users, one of the reasons why some people dislike it and use Micronaut, Quarkus etc. Having used those myself I'm going to migrate to them again in a future project, until Spring get's its act together.

Comment: Sorry to hear the migration wasn't smooth for you. Unfortunately, we had to introduce some breaking changes in order to fix the configuration issues reported by users against v4.

Comment: `Yes I had fixed that, but the next error was ConversionService missing. From that error I realized that for the custom configuration, Spring Batch was not providing defaults but expecting the full configuration for every dependency, which caused me to give up`. This is related to Spring Boot, because you are probably using `@EnableBatchProcessing`. When that annotation is present, you take full control over the configuration of Batch, there is a note about it in the migration guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes.

Comment: I believe this is the cause of the issue. If you remove that annotation, you should get the defaults as in v4. Anyway, we are always open and happy to help if you need any assistance in your migration.

Comment: No I'm not. I am aware and removed @EnableBatchProcessing so that autoconfiguration will work in Spring 3. The problem has nothing to do with that. thr problem is that once I provided the incrementerFactory, I was then required to provide the ConversionService, you see the problem?  Prior to Spring Batch 5, my configuration provided only a datasource and JdbcTemplate for the JobRepository. After Spring Batch 5, that no longer worked and I was required to provide the incrementerFactory and subsequently after that the ConversionService and so on.

Comment: No I'm not. I am aware and removed @EnableBatchProcessing so that autoconfiguration will work in Spring 3. The problem has nothing to do with that. The problem is that I am mandated to provide an incrementerFactory,  and subsequently a ConversionService, you see the problem?  Prior to Spring Batch 5, my configuration only provided only a datasource and JdbcTemplate and that was fine. In a nutshell, Spring Batch 5 does not support the minimal configuration. I really want you to prove me wrong, by providing a custom JobRepository with just a datasource and JdbcTemplate that works

Comment: Thank you for the updates. `I really want you to prove me wrong`: that is not the goal. I am taking your feedback seriously, but since you did not provide a minimal complete example that reproduces the issue, I am trying my best at guessing the configuration that leads to your issue in order to help you efficiently. Based on your feedback, I added an answer with a complete example.

Comment: That is the problem, it was enough before what not now? Why should a prior implementation which supported describing the schema to use for tables managed by spring batch not be sufficient? Makes little sense to me I must contend.

Comment: I discussed this issue with colleagues of mine and they all agree on the point I discussed here. i.e. for the spring job management tables, specifying a datasource type and schema should work with no issues in the new implementation

Answer (score 0):

> Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceProductizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceProductizerConfiguration.class]: No schema scripts found at product 'schema-h2.sql'

I tried to reproduce this issue with what you shared and this error comes from an incorrect value in the properties file here `spring.batch.jdbc.schema=schema-h2.sql`. That property can be either omitted (in which case Spring Boot will default to `classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-@@platform@@.sql`) or set to the full path of the initialization script like: `spring.batch.jdbc.schema=/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql`). Passing only the script file name is not enough (and which could be the cause of the incrementer factory issue, which could not be inferred).

> No I'm not. I am aware and removed @EnableBatchProcessing so that autoconfiguration will work in Spring 3. The problem has nothing to do with that. The problem is that I am mandated to provide an incrementerFactory, and subsequently a ConversionService, you see the problem? Prior to Spring Batch 5, my configuration only provided only a datasource and JdbcTemplate and that was fine. In a nutshell, Spring Batch 5 does not support the minimal configuration.

Here is a minimal complete example with a datasource and jdbc template:

File `src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java`:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager, JdbcTemplate batchJdbcTemplate) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                            System.out.println("Nb persons: " + batchJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from persons", Integer.class));
                            System.out.println("Nb job instances: " + batchJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE", Integer.class));
                            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                        }, batchTransactionManager)
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql")
                .addScript("/persons.sql")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTransactionManager batchTransactionManager(DataSource batchDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(batchDataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate batchJdbcTemplate(DataSource batchDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(batchDataSource);
    }

}
```

File `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

File `resources/persons.sql`

```
create table persons (id int primary key, name varchar);
insert into persons values (1, 'foo');
insert into persons values (2, 'bar');
```

File `resources/application.properties`: empty

If you run this app, it prints:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)

2023-12-04T15:03:12.645+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 21-ea with PID 70973 (/tmp/so77530727/target/classes started by XXX in /tmp/so77530727)
2023-12-04T15:03:12.650+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-04T15:03:13.202+01:00  WARN 70973 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'demoApplication' of type [com.example.demo.DemoApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2023-12-04T15:03:13.221+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2023-12-04T15:03:13.464+01:00  WARN 70973 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'batchDataSource' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory$EmbeddedDataSourceProxy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2023-12-04T15:03:13.470+01:00  WARN 70973 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'batchTransactionManager' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2023-12-04T15:03:13.479+01:00  WARN 70973 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.batch-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2023-12-04T15:03:13.484+01:00  WARN 70973 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$SpringBootBatchConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$SpringBootBatchConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2023-12-04T15:03:13.671+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.5 seconds (process running for 2.19)
2023-12-04T15:03:13.673+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2023-12-04T15:03:13.699+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2023-12-04T15:03:13.727+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step]
Nb persons: 2
Nb job instances: 1
2023-12-04T15:03:13.736+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step] executed in 9ms
2023-12-04T15:03:13.742+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 28ms
2023-12-04T15:03:13.747+01:00  INFO 70973 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false'
```

As a batch user, I provided the custom batch datasource and jdbc template, which were used by the job and job repository, but I was not mandated to provide an incrementerFactory.

Comment: This is what I have now like I said. That is not what I wanted as you can see from my original custom JobRepository.  This is really not useful to me because this is what I already have

Comment: @BreenDeen Did you find a solution?  I am also stuck with this.

Comment: No, unfortunately not with my custom JobRepositoryBean did not work because of all the extra beans needed. I therefore decided to use the autowired JobRepository since I had already defined a datasource, a JdbcTemplate bean. That's how I got it to work,

Comment: By extra it required me to provide a IncrementerFactory, then when I provided that, it required me to provide a ConversionService and I quickly realized the rabbit hole I was going down. I suppose if one wants to provide all those beans it would work but that would be insanity IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I started going down the rabbit hole of defining everything that it needed, like for example the IncrementerFactory, the ConversionService etc, and then I later realized that all of that could be replaced by adding:

```
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
```

After setting all the necessary properties, which would look like this:

```
var jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
```